# Почему в батник не берет элементы из переменной?

Tags: cmd, bat

Написал для батника код. Код засовывает в переменную **pyti_k_15_perebivkam** имена 15-ти файлов **vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4 .... vidov_ska4ali_15.mp4** . Далее он должен сгенерить рандомною цифру 1-15 и взять по сгенереному индексу один элемент из переменной **pyti_k_15_perebivkam** и записать в **imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya**

Попробовал сразу присвоить индекс `set randomIndex=3` какие элементы брать ,  и далее рандомом переназначить **randomIndex** юзая `set /a randomIndex=!random! %% 15 + 1` (смотрите код ниже)

Вот что получилось:
[image]

Если же так делаю `set randomIndex=` или вообще не назначаю (например закоментил) `:: set randomIndex=3` то вообще на выходе пустота:

[image]

- Почему код выдаёт в ответе **vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4 vidov_ska4ali_3.mp4** вместо (как пример) **vidov_ska4ali_10.mp4 vidov_ska4ali_4.mp4** ?

Код:

```
set i=0
for %%x in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15) do (
set /A i+=1
set pyti_k_15_perebivkam[!i!]=vidov_ska4ali_%%x.mp4
)

for /L %%x in (1,1,15) do (
echo !pyti_k_15_perebivkam[%%x]!
)

echo ************

set randomIndex=3
set "skolkoShtykPerebivok=2"
for /L %%x in (1,1,!skolkoShtykPerebivok!) do (
set /a randomIndex=!random! %% 15 + 1
echo !randomIndex!
call set "randomFile=!pyti_k_15_perebivkam[%randomIndex%]!"
set "imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya=!imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya! !randomFile!"
)


echo imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya !imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya!
```

Comment: А разве индексы в пакетных файлах работают?.. Не сходите с ума, перейдите на powershell уже

Comment: мне надо батником, т к связка по рендерингу видео работает у меня имено так

Comment: так-то вы можете запустить powershell из батника...

Comment: а потом powershell'лом запускаем ffmpeg.exe c командами?

Comment: А почему нет?..

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так процесс рандомайза и добавления и все заработало:

```html
   set "skolkoShtykPerebivok=2"
    for /L %%x in (1,1,!skolkoShtykPerebivok!) do (
    set /a randomIndex=!random! %% 15 + 1
    echo randomIndex s vosk !randomIndex!
    call set "randomFile=vidov_ska4ali_!randomIndex!.mp4"
    set "imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya=!imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya! !randomFile!"
    )
    echo imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya !imena_perebivok_dla_dobavleniya!
```